# Can I control the visibility of the generated class with Protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm using [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) (thanks Marc :) ) to serialize my object model, but I want the object model not to be visible outside my assembly (specifically, I want it to be internal).

By default protobuf-net seems to generate public partial classes. Can I tell it to mark the class `internal`?

Here's a cut down version of my `.proto` file:

```
package MyProject.Core.Persistence;

option optimize_for = SPEED;

message DataObject {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
}
```

Which generates the following class definition:

```
[global::System.Serializable,
   global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"DataObject")]
public partial class DataObject : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
{
  public DataObject () {}

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at the moment; however you can edit `csharp.xslt` to suit your own needs.

This doesn't seem a common case, but it could be added as an option easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

you can add the following two lines before your message definition.

```
import "protobuf-net/protogen.proto";
option (.protobuf_net.fileopt).access = INTERNAL;
```

## Full Sample Code:

```
package MyProject.Core.Persistence;

import "protobuf-net/protogen.proto";
option (.protobuf_net.fileopt).access = INTERNAL;

option optimize_for = SPEED;

message DataObject {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
}
```

## Reference:

The definition of message access in mgravell's [protogen.proto](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/master/src/Tools/protogen.proto)

```
enum Access {
    option (.protobuf_net.enumopt) = {
       access: PUBLIC
    };
    INHERIT = 0;
    PUBLIC = 1;
    PRIVATE = 2;
    INTERNAL = 3;
}
```