# Can I control visibility of generated protobuf-classes in Java?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

[I found an answer for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082567/can-i-control-the-visibility-of-the-generated-class-with-protobuf-net), but can't find a way for Java. I'd like to set the visibility of the generated protobuf-classes automatically to private.
Currently, when I compile my .proto-Files, everything is set to public.